Proof of limit using neighborhood argument.
If I want to prove:
For $f:=A\subset\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,
$\lim_{x \to c} f(x)=L$ $\implies$ $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x+c)=L$.
Can I do:
By definition, $\exists L\in\mathbb{R},\forall N_\epsilon (L), \exists N^*_\delta(c):f[N^*_\delta(c) \cap A] \subset N_\epsilon (L) $
Now,
$N_\epsilon (L) \iff L-\epsilon <y <L+\epsilon$
$N^*_\delta (c) \iff c-\delta <x< c+\delta \iff -\delta < x < \delta \iff N^*_\delta (0) $
$f[N^*_\delta(c) \cap A] \subset N_\epsilon (L) \iff L-\epsilon < f(x) <L+\epsilon \iff L-\epsilon < f(x+c) <L+\epsilon \iff f[N^*_\delta(0) \cap A] \subset N_\epsilon (L) $
Therefore, we have
$\exists L\in\mathbb{R},\forall N_\epsilon (L), \exists N^*_\delta(0):f[N^*_\delta(0) \cap A] \subset N_\epsilon (L) $
I see there might be glaring issues but I want to figure out where explicitly would this fail if it does so.
Thanks.

What's $A$ and what does the * mean?


means punctured neighborhood and $A$ means a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, although it seems redundant here. I edited $A$ in the question.

